Delphi 12 does not have a MediaStore
Delphi 12 Android not found Class MediaStore.
Where is MediaStore?
What is the reason for the absence of 'Androidapi.Nin.MediaStore' and is there an alternative solution?
  try
    ColumnIndex := Cursor.getColumnIndex(JMediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    if ColumnIndex >= 0 then
    begin
      Cursor.moveToFirst;
      filePath := JStringToString(Cursor.getString(ColumnIndex));
      // 在这里处理获取到的图片路径 filePath
      ShowMessage('Selected Image Path: ' + filePath);
    end;
  finally
    Cursor.close;
  end;

JMediaStore encountered an error.
